# Setting up MagicalRecord correctly to save rootSavingContext on background thread

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.1

I have been trying out MagicalRecord and MagicalImport for my current project (v2.1). Things are good so far except I sometimes see that my UI thread locks up when I inject a new entity. This is how I insert a new entity :

```
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
         //import an entity here
    }]
```

When saving entities, I have noticed this in my debug console a lot :

```
 Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x1c558da0): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
```

I have gone through MagicalRecord code on github and it seems they're using 3 level MOC strategy mentioned here : http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/. In this case, the root context should save on the background thread and not on the main thread as the log suggests. I use the following line to get the coredata stack up and running :

```
  [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:COREDATA_STORENAME];
```

Am I doing something wrong in the way I set it up? Why is my root context not saving on background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in MagicalRecord. If you need to fix it right away, try switching to the experimental branch, I believe it has been addressed there.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am not sure I understood you completely. Do you mean that MagicalRecord actually saves the root context on background thread or it erroneously says so in the debug log? If it's just the debug log thats faulty and there's no UI locking, then I am fine with 2.1 version otherwise I'd get the experimental branch. Thanks!

Comment: The bug is in the MR_save method, so it's not an erroneous log.

Comment: Switching to experimental branch hasn't solved the problem either. I am not sure what is going on. Most likely I will have to move away from MR and do the data import myself. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, I was partially wrong. Switching to the experimental branch has helped a little bit. Thanks a lot for your help!